# Opening a search url in a new C# file

Tags: c#, html, xamarin.forms

Good sir,

Am having C# file in Xamarin.Forms called WebPage, i wish to open the eSearch Entry in a new Window(in a new C# file) but it isn't working just showing blank page. 
Here is the code.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;


using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WList
{
    public class WebPage: ContentPage
    {
        Entry eSearch;
        Button bButton;
        public WebPage()
        {
            eSearch = new Entry{Placeholder = "Search and go"};

            bButton = new Button { Text = "GO" };
            bButton.Clicked += bButton_Clicked;

            this.Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    eSearch, bButton
                }
            };

        }

        void bButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(eSearch.Text)) { DisplayAlert("Empty", "Search item is empty", "OK"); }
            else
            {
                Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SitePage());
                //Debug.WriteLine(eSearch.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i intend opening the content the user search for in eSearch in a new Window (C# file) called SitePage. Here is the code

Comment: could you show us `SitePage()` code? and I think you also should pass somehow `eSearch.Text` to the `SitePage` maybe via constructor etc.

Comment: You are pushing a new instance of SitePage, but you are not passing the value of eSearch.Text to it.

Comment: how do i go about it

Comment: either pass it in the constructor, or create a public property in SitePage

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your `text` value in the constructor to the new page.

For Example

```
Public class SitePage : ContentPage
{

    public SitePage(string text)
    {
       var entry = new Entry();
       entry.Text = text;
       this.Content = entry;
    }
}
```

You would then navigate to it like:

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SitePage(eSearch.Text));
```